Who's the mastermind behind the MK virus in World's End Harem?
In the anime, when the Minister of State Kihara heard that Chloe was inspecting the secret lab where MK was developed, she became stressed. It seems like it's her idea, or at least she's supported it. Also, she and her headquarters were accused of spreading MK when they're arrested. This confused me.
MC's girlfriend, Elisa, said on the TV that a manager of the company which spread the virus has become a high rank leader in UW. Doesn't this mean it's UW's plot to spread the virus?
Also, the top-tier doctors in Japan were sent to UW, which seems to imply UW had always supported the manufacture of MK. What did Minister of State Kihara stressed over when she learned that someone's looking into the hospital where the first victim was treated?
